# Regex to parse sub domain and domain into separate groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following possible inputs:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/hello.html
http://subdomain.domain.com
https://subdomain.domain.com
subdomain.domain.com
http://domain.com/hello.html
http://domain.com
https://domain.com
domain.com
```

I am trying to create a regular expression that will capture and subdomain into one group and domain into another group. So given the examples above I would get the following matches:

```
Sub Domain Group    Domain Group
--------------------------------
subdomain           domain.com
subdomain           domain.com
subdomain           domain.com
subdomain           domain.com
empty               domain.com
empty               domain.com    
empty               domain.com
empty               domain.com
```

Comment: Are you limited to just regex, or are you using this is a programming language?

Comment: Using C# with regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(https?://)?((?<subdomain>[^\.]+)\.)?(?<domain>[^\./]+\.[^/]+)/?.*$
```

Use explicit capture.

Answer (score 1):

At least reduce some most the handwork by using System.Uri (http://www.dotnetperls.com/uri)

Now you can do:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^((?<subdomain>.+?)\.)*(?<domain>[^\.]*)$");
```

against the `Host` or `DnsSafeHost` properties. Note that my regex has the added benefit of capturing *zero or more* levels of subdomains, in case they interest you

Comment: `@"^(?:(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.)*(?<domain>[^.]*)$"`

Comment: @Qtax: what is your point? You used other sub matches (`?:`, different kleene algebra for non-greedy matches. Meh. Is my `[^\.]` an error? I didn't test it, but I assumed it would be ok to escape the dot even if unnecessarily (other answers do the same)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to force 3 parts out of it like this:

`^(?:https?://)?([^/.]+(?=\.)|)\.?([^/.]+\.[^/]+)/?(.+|)$`
**edit**
or `^(?:https?://)?((?:[^/.]+(?=\.)\.?)*|)([^/.]+\.[^/.]+)/?(.+|)$` to get *all* the subdomains in a single group (including dot, so could require split).
As a side note, I forgot that .Net does a Group object, where `(?<name> something)*` will capture an array of 'name'. So, go with that for a proper solution (@sehe or @qtax, etc)

Positionally, the order is forced into this:
$1 = subdomain
$2 = domain
$3 = the rest

The only required part is the domain.